# sequelize postrges DB Join another table by Id stored in a array of json [JSON]

Tags: javascript, postgresql, sequelize.js

I'm having a hard time with this.
You don't need to ask why. It must be done this way and with this type of column ([JSON]).
In a table that we will call `Home` We have an array of JSON with Id's of users and other data like email.

With one query, I want to be able to find and include the other model.
Let's look at an example.

```js
    Home:{
          id: UUID,
          name:String,
          users: [
            {
              userId: 1234,
              name: String,
            },
            {
              userId: 4321,
              name: String,
            },
          ],
        };
```

```js
        Users: [{
          id:"1234",
          email: String
        }, {
          id:"4321",
          email: String
        }];
```

So this is our data.
I want to make a `Home.findAll()` sequelize query and join them the user's mail at the end.
From what I saw a bit it might be possible with a `jsonB` type and a `sequelize.literal` But I don't find good information/tutorials/responses to help me on the how.

Comment: Do you mean `json[]` instead of `[join]`? The latter is not a valid postgres type.

Comment: yes json[] sorry